# Having Trouble Running An SQL Update Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Forgive me but I'm relatively new to SQL.

I am trying to update a column of a table I created with a function I created but when I run the Update Statement, nothing happens, I just see the underscore flashing (I'm assuming its trying to run it). The Update Statement is updating around 60,000 fields so I assume it should take a little while but it's been 10 minutes and no good.

I would just like to know if anyone knows just some general reasons that the underscore may be flashing.  I know this is super general but I've just never seen this before.

Here's an image of what I'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpUT7.png

EDIT: There are exactly 67,662 records in the table.
I've also just screenshotted the query and linked it.

Comment: how many records are in your table?

Comment: also post your query.

Comment: Is anything actually running?  Do you get another line number if you press Enter?  Maybe you forgot to end your statement with a semicolon (or a '/' if it's a script) and it's waiting for user input.

Comment: Have you updated or deleted data from the table in another session, without committing or rolling back the changes?

Comment: It's not advisable to update though functions.  Packages and procedures do that.

Comment: @Augwa There are 67,662 records in the table and the query is kinda hard to show because it's an old style join on another table as well.

Comment: @MarkLeiber Yup, its running. I can't enter anything and it ended with a semicolon.

Comment: If you were using new-style joins you'd realises you're doing cross joins; there's no link between ap1/r1 and ap2/r2, so your are getting a cartesian product and your subquery is doing a lot more work than you expect, calling `calc_distance` for all those joined rows..

Comment: @AlexPoole Ok, I think I understand what you're saying. Thanks for the advice. I'm not too sure how I'm supposed to link them but I'll start working on that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please put your code into the question as text, not as an image or a link to an image; copying and pasting the contents of your SQL\*Plus window would have worked in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old-style joins have no join condition between the ap1/r1 pair and the ap2/r2 pair, so you're calling your `calc_distance()` function for 67,662 * 67,622 combinations of coordinates. The use of `distinct` is potentially a warning that you know you're getting duplicates. And then there is no correlation between the subquery and the update itself, so you're repeating that for each row in `temproute`. That will take a while.

It looks like you maybe don't want to be looking at the source airport from two copies of the route table; but the source and destination airports from a single copy.

Something like (untested):

```
UPDATE temproute tr
SET distance = (
  SELECT calc_distance(ap2.latitude, ap2.longitude, ap1.latitude, ap1.longitude)
  FROM routes r
  JOIN airports ap1 ON ap1.icaoairport = r.sourceid 
  JOIN airports ap2 ON ap2.icaoairport = r.destid
  WHERE r.routeid = tr.routeid 
);
```

If `temproute` is a copy of `route` too, which the line count implies, then you don't need to refer to route directly at all in the subquery, perhaps.

But I'm speculating about what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. I'll definitely put what you said into use.